# prevent value from changing once formula is applied

Tags: excel

I have the following formula in my activity sheet in the date column

=IF(ISBLANK(A1),"",TODAY())

This is to automatically populate the cell with the current date if A1 is not empty, i have applied this formula to all the cells in column A. But everyday i open the sheet to add my activities the previous days date value automatically changes to the current date, Is there any way to lock the cells value from changing once the formula is applied for the first time or is there an alternate way

Comment: If any of the answers solved your problem, please accept the according answer. Otherwise leave a comment at the answers if it didn't work out for you, so we can try to help you further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the formula is in `B1`:

With iterative calculation (options > formulas > check "enable iterative calculation") you can use this formula:

```
=IF(A1="","",IF(B1="",TODAY(),B1))
```

if anything is in A1 then B2 will show the actual date but if B1 alredy has a value, it shows the old one (open it up days later will still show the old date) but empty out A1 to reset and a new entry will show the actual date again (just switching the value wont work, you need to empty A1 to get the actual date)

Answer (score 1):

Copy the field and **inset as value** in to the same . This way, the formula gets replaced with the value and never changes.

[image: Paste Option]

Otherwise let the formula reference to a static field which has the date in it.